# Getting a string from .ini file

Tags: c++, winapi

Getting a string from .ini file for login not working. Please don't suggest one of those phases or anything. Unless this won't work. B

```
char* pResult = new char[255];
GetPrivateProfileString("login", "uname", "", pResult, 255, "C:\\Program Files\\myfile\\login.ini");
if (pResult == "1"){
    g_pCVar->ConsoleColorPrintf(Color::Purple(),
        "----Login-Succesfull----\n");

}

else{
    g_pCVar->ConsoleColorPrintf(Color::Purple(),
        "----Login-Failed----\n");

}
delete[] pResult;
```

Here is the .ini file.

```
[login]
uname=1
```

Could someone please suggest what the issue is. Could it be because I am reading from programs files. I had an issue when I was reading from temp? Thanks.

Comment: What is `GetPrivateProfileString`?

Comment: @Mohit Jain: Isn't that one of the standard windows functions to read keys from ini files?

Comment: From the docs *This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications.* Use a different way to access ini files. Why aren't you checking the return value for errors?

Comment: So https://github.com/brofield/simpleini for example, and you can use C++ strings and not have to struggle with C strings that are confusing you (needless use of dynamic memory, erroneous pointer comparison ==).

Comment: @DrDonut In that case a tag would help. (Appears to have been added now)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (pResult == "1")
```

This is wrong, here you compare the pointers, not the actual data pointed by those. You should use something like `if (std::strcmp(pResult,"1") == 0)` (`strcmp` is case sensitive)

In `windows` there's also a `_stricmp` (case insensitive).

I remember back in the day I wrote a small helper like this one:

```
std::string get_profile_string(LPCSTR name, LPCSTR key, LPCSTR def, LPCSTR filename)
{
    char temp[1024];
    int result = GetPrivateProfileString(name, key, def, temp, sizeof(temp), filename);
    return std::string(temp, result);
}
```

If small string optimization is enabled, it will be used if `result` is small enough (so no memory allocation would happen). There's a limit of 1024 chars, which you can increase if you need of course.

The `std::string` class overloads the equal to `==` operator so this time `if (pResult == "1")` will actually work.

```
string result = get_profile_string("login", "uname", "", "C:\\Program Files\\myfile\\login.ini");

if (result == "1")
    g_pCVar->ConsoleColorPrintf(Color::Purple(), "----Login-Succesfull----\n");    
else
    g_pCVar->ConsoleColorPrintf(Color::Purple(),"----Login-Failed----\n");
```

But ideally, if you simply want an integer, then you shouldn't use `GetPrivateProfileString` at all. Instead, use `GetPrivateProfileInt`

```
int age = GetPrivateProfileInt("user", "age", 0, "C:\\Program Files\\myfile\\login.ini");

if (age >= 18)
{ }    
else
{ }
```

Comment: I doubt the hint about Int is helpful, as it looks like he's trying to capture a username for a login, using the value of 1 as a simple test.

Comment: @kfsone My bad, I actually didn't read the parameter names. I've updated my answer a bit.

Comment: I'm using int and it works quiet well :) just hoping string would be easier to use but I guess I'll have to use one of those libraries thank tho

Comment: @JakeReid I've updated my answer with a get_profile_string function. Also, if my answer was helpful, don't forget to accept it :P

Comment: *"Small string optimization will be used if the result is small enough"* - Well, no, not necessarily. The C++ Standard doesn't mandate any particular implementation, and any particular implementation of the language can choose to implement this optimization, any other optimizations or no optimizations at all. Small string optimization is strictly optional.